# Pass information from various classes including the main class to swing class?

Tags: java, swing

I am doing a Java project with interface (Swing) . In side the Swing I have created a login form . In side of my main class I read the usernames and passwords from a text file . How can I pass the data to my Swing class ?

Comment: The best way to achieve this is to create your login form on a JPanel, then use JOptionPane to show it on the screen in a modal dialog, and then read the values from the form after it has been processed / closed

Answer (score 1):

Your GUI has to have getters for your text fields. When you read the data from the file, you can pass it to the fields with setText() method. Example:

```
public class GUI {
    private JTextField field1;
    private JTextField field2;
    // other fields and methods including constructor
    public JTextField getField1 () {
        return field1;
    }
    public JTextField getField2 () {
        return field2;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("your_file_path");
        String string1 = scanner.nextLine();
        String string2 = scanner.nextLine();

        gui.getField1().setText(string1);
        gui.getField2().setText(string2);
    }
}
```